# How to get server content from local html file?

Tags: javascript, html, server, cors, local

In detail, I want to access Wikipedia from a local HTML/JS file.
When requesting a file by jQuery:

```js
$.getJSON('http://www.wikipedia.org', function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

I get
`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at wikipedia.org`
Is there any way to work around [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp) ?

Comment: Can you please add  more details what you want to do? Description is lacking for detailing of problem.

Comment: Wikipedia do provide an API which supports JSONP last time I checked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

sure. https://allorigins.win/
I've used this workaround plenty of times

the way it works is that it gets these contents via its own API, and for free use, you can reference their results by pulling data.contents.

using vanilla javascript/fetch statement

```
fetch(`https://api.allorigins.win/get?url=${encodeURIComponent('https://wikipedia.org')}`)
                .then(response => {
                  if (response.ok) return response.json()
                  throw new Error('Network response was not ok.')
                })
                .then(data => console.log(data.contents));
```

Using jQuery .getJSON

```
$.getJSON('https://api.allorigins.win/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('https://wikipedia.org'), function (data) {
                  alert(data.contents);
              });
```

Comment: If this helped, make sure to upvote. If not, explain what I could add to make it better/more descriptive.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot (I'm afraid there were 2 disvotes :( )